# On one page works on another throws: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been through all the answers for this error, but something weird happens in my case.
I have:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    // data echoed here
}
```

I have 3 different behaviors of this:

1.On one page this works perfectly
2.On another page it throws the: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
3.On an empty test page I've just set, where no other code is
(except include to $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
it works, but throws this at me:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Use `var_dump` to see what `query` is returning in each case.

Comment: It throws a bunch of stuff at me when I use var_dump - can post it if it helps, as the only part I understand is this: "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now", but don't know why

Comment: 2: the query failed. use `echo $mysqli->error;` to see the error. 3: That does not have to do with this code, it's probably caused by a `$mysql->connection_error` check.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Special thank you to Lekensteyn - this solved my issue.

What I did is simply reopen the connection before the new query, and now it works.